# customizing Google Sign-In button inline

Tags: google-api, google-plus

"date-width" seem to effect the button width, does anyone know where the documentation to fine tune this button ?

Many thanks for your help -

```
<body>
  <div id="signin-button" class="show">
     <div class="g-signin"
      data-callback=""
      data-approvalprompt="force"
      data-clientid=""
      data-scope=""
      data-height="tall"
      data-width="wide"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
      >
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, here the Google+ Sign-In Button attributes:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#gapi.auth.signIn